# Make a query that will get a specific month from my sales table

Tags: mysql

In my sales table have the date column and the date is formatted like this January 9, 2018, 5:06 pm. How can I specifically get all the sales made from the month of January 2018 using MySQL?

Comment: which data type is the column for date?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you date column is a date data type columns you can use year() and month() function

```
select * from my_table 
where year(my_date_col) = 2018
and month(my_date_col) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the query returned and empty result

Answer (score 0):

Since the column isn't already in a `DATE` format, let's assume it has to stay in its current format for the application purposes and add an auxiliary `DATE` column to select on (because SELECTs will be more optimized this way).

First we add a `VIRTUAL` column (requires MySQL 5.7+), which is a calculated column that is calculated at runtime but not stored on disk. We don't need to store this column on disk because we're going to index it later. Our `VIRTUAL` column will convert the application date's format to a MySQL `DATE`.

Replace `str_date` with your current date column:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
ADD `virtual_date` DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE(`str_date`, '%M %d, %Y, %l:%i %p')) VIRTUAL AFTER `date`;
```

Now add the `INDEX`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (`virtual_date`);
```

Now we can perform a properly indexed `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE virtual_date >= '2018-01-01'
AND virtual_date <= '2018-01-31'
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE virtual_date >= '2018-01-01'
AND virtual_date <= LAST_DAY('2018-01-01')
```

The MySQL `DATE` format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. The latter query is logically simpler; the `LAST_DAY()` function will give you the last `DATE` of the month given a `DATE` or `DATETIME` value.

Comment: Thank you Dan I have tried the query but it returned an empty result

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read your question closely enough. Your date column looks like a VARCHAR type; if possible, you should convert it to a DATE column. If your application requires you to keep it in that format, you could add an auxiliary DATE column. I'll update my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since

> the date is formatted like this January 9, 2018, 5:06 pm

and this is [not recognizable time format for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) I belive the solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date like 'January%2018%';
```

I know this is not a "best practice" as well as storing time in a wrong type.

Comment: Well, try `'%January%2018%'` then.